# perl IO::zlib print plain text file

Tags: perl, zlib

I've a perl script that I'd like for the user to be able to choose whether the output is in Gzip or plain text file. I'm using perl `IO::zlib` and the idea would be to check the output file name and, if it has a `.gz` extension use Gzip, otherwise just print in plain text. I'm using a command like:

`my $EXCL = new IO::Zlib;`

`$EXCL->open($out_file, (substr($out_file, -3) eq '.gz' ? "wb9" : "wT")) || die("ERROR: cannot open EXCL file!") if($out_file);`

but the output file is always compressed!
Am I doing something wrong?

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Why using IO::Zlib for uncompressed files at all?

```
my $fh;
if (substr($out_file, -3) eq '.gz') {
    $fh = IO::ZLib->new($out_file) or die "Error opening $out_file: $!";
} else {
    open $fh, '>', $out_file or die "Error opening $out_file: $!";
}
```

i didn't find any *wT* mode in http://search.cpan.org/~tomhughes/IO-Zlib-1.10/Zlib.pm or http://search.cpan.org/~pmqs/IO-Compress-2.069/lib/Compress/Zlib.pm

PS: It's always good to include the filename and system error ($!) in a file-open related error message.

Comment: I thought of that, but it would be nicer/easier to have it all on one command.

As for the "wT" option, I thought Zlib would use the C zlib library and in its manual it says:

The mode parameter is as in fopen ("rb" or "wb") but can also include a compression level ("wb9") or a strategy [...] 'T' will request transparent writing or appending with no compression and not using the gzip format.

Comment: IO::ZLib->new creates compressed files. Piping the content through an extra module without any reason doesn't make sense, even if it would be able to output plain text.